# need help with boolean algebra (logics)

Tags: logic

for boolean algebra, what is the contrapositive of an "all" statement and an "some not" statement

Comment: The contrapositive only makes sense for an implication, do you have an example at hand?

Comment: Yeah, what Nasenhaar said. Or do you mean negation?

Comment: Some spiders are not arachnids

Comment: All politicians are liars

Comment: It says to find the contrapositive

Comment: The contrapositive only applies to an implication, something like "If Bob is a politician, then bob is a liar. " Trying to find the contrapositive of a statement like "All politicians are liars" makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you feel like posting a picture of the question in your book, or a link to your exercise, Ill have another look at it

Comment: Ill post a picture,

Comment: I guess you could rewrite the statement into the form of an implication, see my answer below

Comment: thanks, Ill do it your way, it was really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the contrapositive of the implication $p \implies q$ is $\neg q \implies \neg p$, you first want to rewrite your statements as an implication. So "All politicians are liers" becomes "If X is a politician, then X is a liar", and the contrapositive is "If X is not a liar, then X is not a politician".